# Embed Google +1 button in an email

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embed Google +1 button without use of JavaScript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15932/embed-google-1-button-without-use-of-javascript)

Is it possible via some ingenious way to include a Google +1 button within an email?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. E-mail is different than trying to embed a link/button on a webpage without JavaScript. Not everyone is using HTML e-mail, and even so, there's only so much one can do with that.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to do it by deconstructing the link created by the [Google Plus One Bookmarklet](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-plus-one-bookmarklet/) but you're looking at a lot hand-crafting plus relying on ctrlq.org to stay around. (Of course, the bookmarklet itself also depends on the latter.)